# Убрать index.php со строки запроса

Tags: yii, php, php-frameworks

У меня ссылки ввида:

**http://localhost/index.php/website/action**

Как превратить их **http://localhost/website/action**

МОжет выложите корректный Htaccess.

Опция `'showScriptName' => false` не помогла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опция 'showScriptName' => false,'urlFormat'=>'path'  и в .htaccess пишите

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Выйшло с N-раза....Благодарен